# Compile error in my do/while statements?

Tags: java

I created 3 classes Circle, Rectangle, and RightTriangle using my FigureGeometry interface. This program is supposed to take input run calculation using the different classes.

I'm getting a couple of errors with my do/while statement. The do statement says "Illegal start of type". My while statement say the same and "can't find variable option".

I've tried searching for other questions on here/google, but I can't find anything that has helped with my code. It is always something like an extra bracket but as far as I can tell there isn't anything extra here.

I've double checked that all my open/close brackets match up. I've tried having my option variable in the do statement (which I was certain wasn't correct, but I was just trying some different things). I'm just not sure what the issue is?

```
package figuregeometry;

import java.util.Scanner;
public class FigGeometryCalculator
{

    //========================MAIN==============================================
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        float height;
        float width;
        float length;
        float radius;
        float degrees;

        String menu = "Would you like to figure the geometry for a: " + "\n"
        + "1. Circle" + "\n" 
        + "2. Rectangle" + "\n"
        + "3. Right Triangle" + "\n"
        + "0. Exit";

        do
        {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            int option = in.nextInt();

            switch(option)
            {
                case 1: System.out.println("Enter radius: ");
                        radius = in.nextFloat();
                        System.out.println("Enter Degrees of sector: ");
                        degrees = in.nextFloat();
                        Circle newCircle = new Circle(radius, degrees);

                        System.out.println("Set Scale: ");
                        newCircle.setScale(in.nextInt());
                        newCircle.toString();
                        break;

                case 2: System.out.println("Enter length: ");
                        length = in.nextFloat();
                        System.out.println("Enter width: ");
                        width = in.nextFloat();
                        Rectangle newRectangle = new Rectangle(length, width);

                        System.out.println("Set Scale: ");
                        newRectangle.setScale(in.nextInt());
                        newRectangle.toString();
                        break;

                case 3: System.out.println("Enter Length: ");
                        length = in.nextFloat();
                        System.out.println("Enter Height: ");
                        height = in.nextFloat();
                        RightTriangle newTriangle = new RightTriangle(length, width);

                        System.out.println("Set Scale: ");
                        newTriangle.setScale(in.nextInt());
                        newTriangle.toString();
                        break;

                case 0: 
                        System.out.println("Exit");
                        break;

                default: System.out.println("Not an a valid option. Please try again.");

            }
        }while(option != 0);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can not have any access modifiers inside a method. `public float height;` should be `float height;`

Comment: Could be that you have `public` before local variable definitions.

Comment: ok, that makes sense as well. I have corrected this issue, but I'm still not sure what is wrong with my do/while statements?

Comment: It will loop forever. the in.nextInt() must be inside the loop statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problems:

Remove all invalid modifiers. That is, change:

```
public float height;
public float width;
public float length;
public float radius;
public float degrees;
```

To:

```
float height;
float width;
float length;
float radius;
float degrees;
```

Maybe not a direct answer to your question but you need to put your input received `option = in.nextInt();` inside the loop. Otherwise you will end up with an infinite loop.

For example, if the user chooses '1', option becomes 1 and is never updated inside the loop so your loop will run forever.

**EDIT:**

Just to clarify since I see you didn't understand.
You don't put `int option = in.nextInt();` inside the loop, you put everything but the `int`. (so `option = in.nextInt();` inside the loop). You say `int option;` outside the loop.

So:

```
int option;  // created outside the loop
do {
    System.out.print(menu);
    option = in.nextInt();  // used inside the loop
    switch(option)
    {
        // CASES AND CODE
    }
} while(option != 0);
```

That is why you are getting an error because your variable option isn't visible to the while loop so the loop cannot compare something with 0 if it cannot find it.

In general, try not to create anything inside loops, and create outside of them to prevent unnecessary object creation. Another example, your `Scanner` object should be created outside of your loop.

Put the statement `Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);` outside the loop then use it with `option = in.nextInt();` the way I described above.

Comment: There wouldn't be any stack overflow, it would just loop forever.

Comment: Maybe not a Stack Overflow as there is no recursion occuring, but quite possibly an OutOfMemoryError.

Comment: There's nothing that could cause a memory leak in there.

Comment: @nem yes, it's the "(while there's memory)" that I was objecting to.

Comment: @chiastic-security i see, i removed it from my answer, you're right

Comment: thanks, I did figure out that last part about the option variable after I edited the code.. This seems to have fixed all of my errors.